# Root certificate for Hyperledger fabric-ca

Tags: ssl, certificate, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have one simple question and I will be very grateful if someone could help me. So when I run fabric-ca server, what `sh -c 'fabric-ca-server init -b admin:adminpw'` does is that it creates self signed certificate, and this will be root certificate for fabric-ca, under this certificate `admin:adminpw` user will be creted.  so here is my question: why the hell I need `ca-cert.pem` and `ca-key.pem` files inside `etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server` folder? when do I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `init` command will create a self-signed certificate for the CA, but it has no association to `admin:adminpw`. That part of the command only registers a bootstrap identity with name of 'admin' and a password of 'adminpw'.

The `ca-key.pem` file is the secret key and will be used to sign certificates when identities enroll with the CA. The `ca-cert.pem` is the public component and is used in the verification of certificates, it comes into play when you define your channel and local peer MSPs.